# dataset stuck in ckan which cannot be removed, cannot open (404)

Tags: dataset, http-status-code-404, ckan

I am removing all the datasets from CKAN and recreate them. However, there is one last dataset which I cannot delete. 
I am using the ckan API to do removal from python. I can search and get the dataset from both UI and command line, however, when I click on the link to the dataset in browser, it gives me 404 page. When I try to create the dataset with same name, it failed with name conflict. 
any clue?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the error stacktrace?

Comment: There is no error. Feels like the all to the endpoint was fine. but nothing gets deleted. When opening the item from listing page, the return code is 404. So the data is somehow removed, but the trail stuck in the db or solr.

Comment: Is this a production install of CKAN? If so, there should be more detail in your server logs (e.g. `/var/log/apache2/ckan_default.error.log`).  What API endpoint are you using to delete the dataset?

Comment: @user3366016 Thanks for the info and sorry for the late replay. I am using docker setup from the official repo and running on `production.ini`. Not sure if this is the reason, but there is no apache nor log file in the the log folder for CKAN.

Comment: I am using `package_delete` and `package_purge` to delete and purge the dataset

Comment: try to clean search-index @VicDing

Comment: @VicDing run in the container paster --plugin=ckan search-index rebuild -c /etc/ckan/default/production.ini

Comment: tino097 @Zoran Pandovski : the reindex worked in my case. Thank you both for the help? Now how can I mark the comments as solution? :)

Comment: @VicDing I will add the comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rebuild the search index. This is useful to prevent search indexes from getting out of sync with the main database. You should run:

CKAN >= version 2.8:

```
ckan -c /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini search-index rebuild
```

CKAN < 2.8:

```
paster --plugin=ckan search-index rebuild -c /etc/ckan/default/production.ini
```

For more info please check [official docs](https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/maintaining/paster.html#search-index-rebuild-search-index)